# How to convert JSON which has array to Java objects

Tags: java, json, gson

Unable to convert a JSON string which has few elements and an array inside it. 
On UI I need to feed the array to bootstrap table.

**JSON string:**

```
 {
    "IsOperationSuccessful": true,
    "IsResult": true,
    "StatusCode": "OK",
    "Response": [{
        "PlaylistCreatedBy": "XYZ",
        "PlaylistCreatedOn": "10/10/2019 14:10",
        "PlaylistDisplayTitle": "blah",
        "PlaylistId": 101,
        "PlaylistScheduledReleaseTime": "10/10/2019 14:10"
    }, {
        "PlaylistCreatedBy": "HHJK",
        "PlaylistCreatedOn": "10/10/2019 14:10",
        "PlaylistDisplayTitle": "blah blah",
        "PlaylistId": 102,
        "PlaylistScheduledReleaseTime": "10/10/2019 14:10"
    }, {
        "PlaylistCreatedBy": "HJHJ",
        "PlaylistCreatedOn": "10/10/2019 14:10",
        "PlaylistDisplayTitle": "UIUI",
        "PlaylistId": 103,
        "PlaylistScheduledReleaseTime": "10/10/2019 14:10"
    }, {
        "PlaylistCreatedBy": "KJK",
        "PlaylistCreatedOn": "10/10/2019 14:10",
        "PlaylistDisplayTitle": "kkj",
        "PlaylistId": 104,
        "PlaylistScheduledReleaseTime": "10/10/2019 14:10"
    }],
    "Total": 4
}
```

The code that I have added so far:

```
    PreRecordedCall morningCallResponse = new PreRecordedCall();
    JSONArray playListinfo = null; 
    String testResponse = "//Json Goes here "
    JSONObject finalJson = new JSONObject();
    finalJson.put("testResponse", testResponse); 
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    morningCallResponse = gson.fromJson(testResponse, 
    PreRecordedCall.class); 
    playListinfo =  morningCallResponse.getPreRecordplayListInformation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create 2 POJOs (says `Response` and `PreRecordedCall`) as follows. 
The `Response` is for the JSON array with key "Response" and the `PreRecordedCall` is for the whole JSON object. The key is to use `List<Response>` to store JSON array.

BTW, to follow the naming rule for variables in POJOs with lowerCamelCase, I used `@SerializedName` for object name mapping.

**Class Response**

```
static class Response {
    @SerializedName("PlaylistCreatedBy")
    private String playlistCreatedBy;

    @SerializedName("PlaylistCreatedOn")
    private String playlistCreatedOn;

    @SerializedName("PlaylistDisplayTitle")
    private String playlistDisplayTitle;

    @SerializedName("PlaylistId")
    private int playlistId;

    @SerializedName("PlaylistScheduledReleaseTime")
    private String playlistScheduledReleaseTime;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

**Class PreRecordedCall**

```
static class PreRecordedCall {
    @SerializedName("IsOperationSuccessful")
    private Boolean isOperationSuccessful;

    @SerializedName("IsResult")
    private Boolean isResult;

    @SerializedName("StatusCode")
    private String statusCode;

    @SerializedName("Response")
    private List<Response> response;

    @SerializedName("Total")
    private int total;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

Then you can simply convert the JSON string to pre-defined POJOs as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
PreRecordedCall preRecordedCall = gson.fromJson(testResponse, PreRecordedCall.class);
System.out.println(preRecordedCall.getResponse().size());
```

**Console output**

> 4

And if you are using `Jackson` as your JSON parser, change `@SerializedName` to `@JsonProperty` and you can get the same result by following code snippet.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PreRecordedCall preRecordedCall = mapper.readValue(testResponse, PreRecordedCall.class);
System.out.println(preRecordedCall.getResponse().size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below code works for you:

```
String finalJson= "//Json Goes here ";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    PreRecordedCall morningCallResponse = objectMapper.readValue(json, PreRecordedCall.class);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but my response needs to be JSONArray not a List<Response> because I need to feed this response to a Bootstrap table.